# Developing Windows Phone 7.5 apps in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-7, windows-10

Is it possible to develop WP 7.5 apps (in Visual Studio 2012 + Windows Phone 8 SDK) after upgrading pc from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10 Pro?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately windows 10 is supporting windows phone 8 and above